# Ensure template parameter is an enum class

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

Is there a way to ensure a template parameter is an enum-class type?

I know `type_traits` has `std::is_enum`, but I don't want it to match regular enums, just enum_classes.

Example of the wanted effect:

```
enum class EnumClass {};
enum Enum {};
class Class {};

template <typename T>
void Example()
{
    static_assert(/* T is EnumClass */, "`T` must be an enum class");
}

Example<EnumClass>(); // Ok
Example<Enum>(); // Error
Example<Class>(); // Error
```

I am using C++11, and unfortunately cannot go any higher (though I'd be curious to know the solution anyway, even if it involves newer standards).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can achieve it with:

```
template<typename T>
using is_class_enum = std::integral_constant<
   bool,
   std::is_enum<T>::value && !std::is_convertible<T, int>::value>;
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/RrG9GS) a demo.

---

If you prefer using SFINAE, the same can be achieved with:

```
template<typename T, typename _ = void>
struct is_class_enum : std::false_type {
};

template<typename T>
struct is_class_enum <
  T,
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value &&
                          !std::is_convertible<T, int>::value>::type> :
    public std::true_type {
};
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're simply depending on the fact that enum classes are not implicitly convertible to integrals? Isn't it possible to define an implicit conversion operator?

Comment: @GiladNaaman how do you define an implicit operator from an `enum class`?

Comment: Yeah, my bad, you can't actually define operators or functions inside an `enum class`.

Comment: Shouldn't `std::underlying_type_t<T>` be used instead of just an `int` as a `std::is_convertible<>` check type?

Comment: @SergeyNikitin There's no point, and doing `underlying_type` right is actually tricky (you cannot instantiate it until you know that `T` is actually an enum type).