# How to check if a type is an enum class?

Tags: c++, enums, enum-class

With the following code I can check at compile time if type E is an enum:

```
static_assert(true == std::is_enum<E>::value, "Must be an enum");
```

How can I check if it is an `enum class`?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807629/ensure-template-parameter-is-an-enum-class) they suggest to add the check `!std::is_convertible<T, int>::value`, but it looks like a trick. Is there a better way?

Comment: My first idea would be an SFINAE test for something like "can you add integers to it" , but that can be fooled by a free `operator+`...

Comment: There is no built-in function in the Standard Library. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724783/is-it-possible-to-determine-if-a-type-is-a-scoped-enumeration-type) seems to do the trick.

Comment: _"Is there a better way?"_: according to what criterion? As is, this question is opinion-based ;)

Comment: *"but it looks like a trick"* Everything about template metaprogramming is a trick. It's a C++ feature that was discovered, not designed.

Comment: @YSC obviously that does not look like a trick

Comment: @Ron, your link answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you care if it is an enum class? (If the reason involves avoiding an implicit conversion to `int`, then your "trick" might be more appropriate than something saying "is an enum class".)

Comment: @Slava I wager you're being sarcastic (and if you do: :D), but just to be sure (Poe's law after all) ... On what criterion does a solution looks more or less like a trick? :)

Comment: @YSC non tricky code should clearly show intentions. For example `std::is_enum` does, `std::doing_that_with_int and std::not_doing_this_with_char` does not.